# Can't find the mistake in my inductive step

Tags: induction

Few days ago I was solving some induction execises, and I tried and solved this one.

## Statement

What is wrong with this “proof”?

“Theorem” For every positive integer n, if x and y are positive integers with max(x, y) = n, then x = y.

Basis Step: Suppose that n = 1. If max(x, y) = 1 and x and y are positive integers, we have x = 1 and y = 1.

Inductive Step: Let k be a positive integer. Assume that whenever max(x, y) = k and x and y are positive integers, then x = y. Now let max(x, y) = k + 1, where x and y are positive integers. Then max(x − 1, y − 1) = k, so by the inductive hypothesis, x − 1 = y − 1. It follows that x = y, completing the inductive step.

## Solution, taken from the original book

The mistake is in applying
the inductive hypothesis to look at max(x − 1, y − 1), because
even though x and y are positive integers, x − 1 and y − 1
need not be (one or both could be 0)

## Now my question

After solving the problem I wrote my own inductive step, assuming the same hypothesis. I did it just for fun, but now, even knowing that my inductive step is wrong, I can't find the mistake. I need to know what is wrong in my inductive step and why.

## My inductive step

Inductive Step: Let k be a positive integer. Assume that whenever max(x, y) = k and x and y are positive integers, then x = y. Since max(x, y) = k and x and y are positive integers with x = y, I plus 1 to both x and y. Then max(x + 1, y + 1) = k + 1. It follows that x + 1 = y + 1 because x = y, completing the inductive step.

Comment: Did you mean to post on [math.se]?

Answer (score 0):

Your inductive step is not bringing you closer to the base case.

Comment: not the mine, but the idea is to make it bottom up, is it wrong? well, it is, but exactly where and why?

Answer (score 0):

The conclusion of your inductive step doesn't match the original theorem.

The theorem says that for a given n, it is the case that for *all* positive integers x, y with max(x, y) = n, x must be equal to y.

Your inductive step only gives you max(x+1, y+1) = n (with n = k+1). But not all positive integers have the form x+1 (with x also being a positive integer): 1 is a counterexample. Therefore your proof doesn't cover all possible values of x and y.